# MapKit Tile Overlay takes a long time to load

Tags: ios, mapkit, swift5

I am trying to build an app which loops through overlay tiles. The problem is the map tiles take forever to reload when the map displays. What is the best way around this issue? I'm not sure if it is a caching issue which I think MapKit does itself. My guess is it is a Swift redrawing issue. My code is below, and I appreciate your help.

```
//  Copyright 2020 Oklahoma Weather Blog
//

import SwiftUI

import MapKit
import SwiftSoup


/*
struct RadarMapView: UIViewRepresentable {

    
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var tileRenderer = MKOverlayRenderer()
    
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        guard let tileOverlay = overlay as? MKTileOverlay else {
            return MKOverlayRenderer()
        }
        
        return MKTileOverlayRenderer(tileOverlay: tileOverlay)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        var template = "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        template = "https://tilecache.rainviewer.com/v2/ radar/1600575600/512/{z}/{x}/{y}/6/0_1.png"
        let overlay = MKTileOverlay(urlTemplate:template)

      overlay.canReplaceMapContent = false
        let mapView = MKMapView(frame: .zero)
        var renderedOverlay = MKTileOverlayRenderer(tileOverlay: overlay)
        mapView.addOverlay(overlay, level: .aboveLabels)
        mapView.setNeedsDisplay()
        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {

        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.3, longitudeDelta: 0.3)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
        
    
        view.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
 */

func getTimesURL() -> [String] {
    let myURLString = "https://api.rainviewer.com/public/maps.json"
    guard let myURL = URL(string: myURLString) else {
        printToConsole("Error: \(myURLString) doesn't seem to be a valid URL")
        return []
    }

    do {
        let myHTMLString = try String(contentsOf: myURL)
        do {
           let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(myHTMLString)
            
            let text = try doc.text()
            let resultArray = text.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "[]"))
                .components(separatedBy:",")
            return resultArray

            
        } catch Exception.Error( _, let message) {
            printToConsole(message)
        } catch {
            printToConsole("error")
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        printToConsole("Error: \(error)")
    }
    return []
    
}




func getOverlays() -> [MKTileOverlay] {
    var overlays: [MKTileOverlay] = []
    for time in getTimesURL() {
        let template = "https://tilecache.rainviewer.com/v2/radar/\(time)/256/{z}/{x}/{y}/7/1_1.png"
        
        let overlay = MKTileOverlay(urlTemplate:template)
        overlays.append(overlay)
    }

    return overlays
    
}


struct RadarView: View {
    private static let mapStyles: [MKMapType] = [.hybrid, .hybridFlyover, .mutedStandard, .satellite, .satelliteFlyover, .standard]
    @State var mapTime = "1600585200"
    

    let cache = NSCache<NSString, MKTileOverlay>()
    
    @AppStorage("selectedMapStyle") var selectedMapStyle = 0
    
    @State private var showingSheet = false
    
    private static var overlayArray: [MKTileOverlay] {
        getOverlays()
    }
    
    private static var timeArray: [String] {
        getTimesURL()
    }
    
    func dateToString(_ epoch: String) -> String{


        let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "MM/dd hh:mm a"

        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(Int(epoch)!))
        return dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date)

    }
    
    
    @State private var timeIndex: Double = 0
    @State private var loopMap: Bool = false
    @State var radarTimer: Timer?

    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                RadarMapView(mapStyle: RadarView.mapStyles[selectedMapStyle], overlay: RadarView.overlayArray[Int(timeIndex)]).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
                
            HStack{
                VStack{
                    Slider(value: $timeIndex.animation(.linear), in: 0...9, step: 1)
                    Text("\(dateToString(RadarView.timeArray[Int(timeIndex)]))")
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    loopMap.toggle()
                    if loopMap {
                        radarTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { _ in
                                // do something here
                            if RadarView.overlayArray.count > 0 {
                                withAnimation{
                                timeIndex = Double((Int(timeIndex) + 1) % RadarView.overlayArray.count )
                                }
                            }

                            }
       

                    } else {
                        radarTimer?.invalidate()
                    }
                }, label: {
                    
                    if !loopMap { Text("Loop") }
                    else { Text("Pause") }
                })
                

            }.padding(.horizontal).padding(.horizontal).background(Color.init(UIColor.systemBackground).opacity(0.75))

            }
            
            HStack(){
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    /*
                    selectedMapStyle = (selectedMapStyle + 1) % mapStyles.count
                    */
                    showingSheet.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "map.fill").resizable()
                        .renderingMode(.template)
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                }).padding()
            }.padding(.horizontal).padding(.bottom).background(Color.init(UIColor.systemBackground).opacity(0.75))

        }.actionSheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
            ActionSheet(title: Text("What map style do you want?"), message: Text("Please select one option below"), buttons: [
                .default(Text("Muted")) { self.selectedMapStyle = 2 },
                .default(Text("Satellite")) { self.selectedMapStyle = 3 },
                .default(Text("Satellite w/ Roads")) { self.selectedMapStyle = 0 },
                .default(Text("Satellite 3-D")) { self.selectedMapStyle = 4 },
                .default(Text("3-D Satellite w/ Roads")) { self.selectedMapStyle = 1 },
                .default(Text("Standard")) { self.selectedMapStyle = 5 },
                .cancel(Text("Dismiss"))
            ])
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom).navigationBarTitle("Radar")
    }
}

struct RadarMapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var mapStyle: MKMapType
    var overlay: MKTileOverlay
    

    class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var parent: RadarMapView

        init(_ parent: RadarMapView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
            
            let renderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            
            return renderer
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        return MKMapView()
    }
    
    
    

    func updateUIView(_ mapView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        
        // var template = "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        //1600626600
    
        mapView.mapType = self.mapStyle
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator

        let overlays = mapView.overlays
        mapView.addOverlay(overlay)
        
        let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 50000
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 33.7490, longitude: -84.3880)
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location,
                                                  latitudinalMeters: regionRadius * 2.0, longitudinalMeters: regionRadius * 2.0)
        mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
        for overlay in overlays {
            // remove all MKPolyline-Overlays
            if overlay is MKTileOverlay {
                mapView.removeOverlay(overlay)
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct RadarView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RadarView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a few days ago (with a different tile server) and solved it by using 512px tiles.

My theory is, that almost nobody uses 256px tiles, so servers don't cache them.

Do something like

```
func getOverlays() -> [MKTileOverlay] {
    var overlays: [MKTileOverlay] = []
    for time in getTimesURL() {
        let template = "https://tilecache.rainviewer.com/v2/radar/\(time)/512/{z}/{x}/{y}/7/1_1.png"
    
        let overlay = MKTileOverlay(urlTemplate:template)
        overlay.tileSize = CGSize(width: 512, height: 512)
        overlays.append(overlay)
    }

    return overlays

}
```